# Make the parent item text (not just the arrow) open the submenu?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

How to make the parent item text open the submenu, right now only clicking the arrows make the submenu open but clicking the parent text just closes the menu. Optimally clicking either the text or the arrows will cause the submenu to open unfortunately I don't know how to achieve this. I have attached the snippets of code (css and jquery) that are currently used to achieve the effect of the dropdown submenu.

```js
<script >
    jQuery(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("body ul.et_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children, body ul.et_mobile_menu  li.page_item_has_children").append('<a href="#" class="mobile-toggle"></a>');
            $('ul.et_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children .mobile-toggle, ul.et_mobile_menu li.page_item_has_children .mobile-toggle').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('dt-open');
                $(this).parent('li').find('ul.children').first().toggleClass('visible');
                $(this).parent('li').find('ul.sub-menu').first().toggleClass('visible');
            });
            iconFINAL = 'P';
            $('body ul.et_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children, body ul.et_mobile_menu li.page_item_has_children').attr('data-icon', iconFINAL);
            $('.mobile-toggle').on('mouseover', function() {
                $(this).parent().addClass('is-hover');
            }).on('mouseout', function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('is-hover');
            })
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

```css
/*adjust the new toggle element which is added via jQuery*/

ul.et_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children .mobile-toggle,
ul.et_mobile_menu li.page_item_has_children .mobile-toggle,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l ul.et_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children .mobile-toggle,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l ul.et_mobile_menu li.page_item_has_children .mobile-toggle {
    width: 44px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px !important;
    max-height: 44px;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: transparent;
}


/*some code to keep everyting positioned properly*/

ul.et_mobile_menu>li.menu-item-has-children,
ul.et_mobile_menu>li.page_item_has_children,
ul.et_mobile_menu>li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l ul.et_mobile_menu>li.menu-item-has-children,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l ul.et_mobile_menu>li.page_item_has_children,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l ul.et_mobile_menu>li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children {
    position: relative;
}


/*remove default background color from menu items that have children*/

.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children>a,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children>a {
    background-color: transparent;
}


/*hide the submenu by default*/

ul.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu,
#main-header ul.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l ul.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu,
.et-db #main-header ul.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}


/*show the submenu when toggled open*/

ul.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu.visible,
#main-header ul.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu.visible,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l ul.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu.visible,
.et-db #main-header ul.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu.visible {
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}


/*adjust the toggle icon position and transparency*/

ul.et_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children .mobile-toggle,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l ul.et_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children .mobile-toggle {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
}


/*submenu toggle icon when closed*/

ul.et_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children .mobile-toggle::after,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l ul.et_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children .mobile-toggle::after {
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "ETModules";
    content: '\33';
    color: #00d263;
    background: #f0f3f6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 3px;
}


/*submenu toggle icon when open*/

ul.et_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children.dt-open>.mobile-toggle::after,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l ul.et_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children.dt-open>.mobile-toggle::after {
    content: '\32';
}


/*add point on top of the menu submenu dropdown*/

.et_pb_menu_0.et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    top: -14px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: '';
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #ffffff;
}


/*adjust the position of the hamburger menu*/

.mobile_menu_bar {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 0;
}


/*force the background color and add a rounded border*/

.et_pb_menu_0.et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu,
.et_pb_menu_0.et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu ul {
    background-color: #ffffff!important;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: <script > maybe this is the error. Write <script> without space. Could you post HTML either.

Comment: Nope, tried it nothing changed.